# macos big sur network issues

Tags: macos

I updated my `MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)` to latest `macOS Big Sur - 11.3 (20E232)` and right away started to experiencing some network issues such as this:

```
alexus@mbp ~ % time host google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
host google.com  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.010 total
alexus@mbp ~ % grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.86.1
alexus@mbp ~ % netstat -rn | egrep 'default.*en0'
default            192.168.86.1       UGScg          en0       
alexus@mbp ~ % time ping -c1 192.168.86.1
PING 192.168.86.1 (192.168.86.1): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.86.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
ping -c1 192.168.86.1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 11.014 total
alexus@mbp ~ %
```

yet I'm in `Chrome` writing you this question to you fine community)

a lot of apps opens slow (~1-2 mins), definitely not as quick as they were before (1-2 secs), `App Store` never opens...

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to pin point the issue to [Objective-See: LuLu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) ...

... As soon as I disable it everything started to works!

I went ahead and created an issue: https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu/issues/360

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit strange.

Also, this is a shot in the dark so don't down vote me. My best guess is that chrome is using the dns via https. Wireshark or tcpdump would be your friend here.

Do you have a ipv6 address?

https://duo.com/decipher/google-makes-dns-over-https-default-in-chrome

Comment: Check out http://ipv6.test-ipv6.com

Comment: my router supports ipv6, but I don't believe my provider does ... but i think dns over https that's a valid guess... that only explains why chrome is working, but the rest of the system still kinda ...

Comment: Sounds like you are using a vpn.  Many of these VPNs might have local subnet isolation. Hence, you cannot ping your local gateway/dns provider. The grep reference shows en0 interface but there should be tunnel interface above it. If you grep default, you will likely have a tunnel or virtual interface for the vpn that ends up being pushed to 192.168.86.1   in an encrypted tunnel. Also, apple will blackhole vpn traffic that attempts to connect to the app store via some vpn providers.